# Powershell circular dependencies

Tags: powershell, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

I have a scenario where I *THINK* a circular dependency is the right answer. In my actual code I have a class that contains some data that is used for token replacements. That class contains other classes for the data, and contains a method that does the lookup of token values and returns the value. However, those dependent classes need to be validated, and some of those values are dependent on lookups. So, I have mocked up this code to validate the approach.

```
class Tokens {
    [Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]$primaryData
    [Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]$secondaryData

    Tokens ([Secondary]$seconday) {
        $this.primaryData = [Ordered]@{
            '1' = 'One'
            '2' = 'Two'
            '3' = 'Three'
            '4' = 'Four'
            '5' = 'Five'
        }
        $this.secondaryData = $seconday.secondaryData
    }

    [String] GetToken ([String]$library, [String]$item) {
        return $this.$library.$item
    }
    [Void] SetToken ([String]$library, [String]$item, [String]$value) {
        $this.$library.$item = $value
    }

    [String] ToString () {
        [Collections.Generic.List[String]]$toString = [Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()

        foreach ($key in $this.primaryData.Keys) {
            $toString.Add("$key : $($this.primaryData.$key)")
        }
        foreach ($key in $this.secondaryData.Keys) {
            $toString.Add("$key : $($this.secondaryData.$key)")
        }

        return [string]::Join("`n", $toString)
    }
}

class Secondary {
    [Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]$secondaryData

    Secondary () {
        $this.secondaryData = [Ordered]@{
            'A' = 'a'
            'B' = 'b'
            'C' = 'c'
            'D' = 'd'
            'E' = 'e'
        }
    }

    [Void] Update ([Tokens]$tokensReference) {
        $tokensReference.SetToken('secondaryData', 'A', 'A')
        $tokensReference.SetToken('secondaryData', 'B', "$($tokensReference.GetToken('secondaryData', 'A')) and $($tokensReference.GetToken('secondaryData', 'B'))")
    }

    [String] ToString () {
        [Collections.Generic.List[String]]$toString = [Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()

        foreach ($key in $this.secondaryData.Keys) {
            $toString.Add("$key : $($this.secondaryData.$key)")
        }

        return [string]::Join("`n", $toString)
    }
}

CLS
$secondary = [Secondary]::new()
$tokens = [Tokens]::new($secondary)
$secondary.Update($tokens)

Write-Host "$($tokens.ToString())"
```

This is working, exactly as expected. however, the idea of circular dependency injection has my hair standing on end. Like, it could be a real problem, or at least is a code smell. So, my question is, am I on the right track, or is this a dead end and I just haven't found that end yet? Given that PowerShell isn't "fully" object oriented yet, I imagine there could be some uniquely PS related issues, and everything I have found searching for *Powershell Circular Dependency* talks about removing them. So far I haven't found anything about when it is appropriate and how to do it well.
And, assuming it is a valid approach, is there anything obvious in this simplified implementation that could lead to problems or could be better done some other way?

EDIT: OK, so perhaps I am going to refine my vocabulary a bit too. I was thinking circular dependency since Secondary is a dependency, or member perhaps, of Tokens, and then I update Secondary from inside Secondary, while referencing data from Secondary, via the method in Tokens.

To clarify (I hope) the ultimate goal, these lookups are for program specific data, which I have in XML files. So, for example the data file for Autodesk Revit 2021 would include these three items

```
<item id="GUID" type="literal">{7346B4A0-2100-0510-0000-705C0D862004}</item>
<item id="installDataKey" type="registryKeyPath">HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[Revit 2021~GUID]</item>
<item id="displayName" type="registryPropertyValue" path="installDataKey">Revit 2021</item>
```

In actual use I would want to get the DisplayName property found in the key defined in `<item id="installDataKey">`, and if the value matches the value in `<item id="displayName">` then I might also look for the value of the `DisplayVersion` property in the same key, and make decisions based on that. But because there are new versions every year, and 20+ different software packages to address, managing these data files is a pain. So I want to validate the data I have in the files against a machine that actually has the software installed, to be sure I have my data correct. Autodesk is famous for changing things for no good reason, and often for some very customer hostile reasons. So, things like referencing the GUID as data and reusing it as a token, i.e. the `[Revit 2021~GUID]` above, saves effort. So during the validation process only, I would want to set the GUID, then do the standard token replacement to convert `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[Revit 2021~GUID]` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{7346B4A0-2100-0510-0000-705C0D862004}` and should that key actually be found, use it to validate about 20 other registry and file paths as well as the actual value of DisplayName. If everything validates I will sign the XML, and in actual use signed XML will basically treat everything as a literal and no validation is done, or rather it was prevalidated.
But before use a reference to `[product~installDataKey]` when the current product is `Revit 2021` would resolve first to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[Revit 2021~GUID]` then to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{7346B4A0-2100-0510-0000-705C0D862004}` at which point the code could use it as a registry path and see if Revit 2021 is in fact installed.
So, 99.9% of the time, I would instantiate Tokens with a constructor that just includes the full dataset and move on. But on the .1% of occasions where I am validating the data itself, I need to be able to read the xml, set the value for that GUID and immediately use the lookup to validate that Autodesk hasn't done something stupid like move some data out of the GUID key and into a secondary key. They have done that before.
I also might want to replace `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` with a token like `[windows~uninstallKey]` just to make life easier there too.

Hopefully that makes some sense. It's a mess to be sure, but anything to do with Autodesk is a mess.

Comment: There's no "circular dependency injection" here. `[Secondary]` can be instantiated without a `[Tokens]` reference. You do, however, now have _shared state_ between the two, which may or may not become problematic. Can you expand on "used for token replacements" - what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: One way to get out of a circular dependency is to do a [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), meaning load the data for a specific argument (and [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) it for performance) when you need it instead of staticaly preloading everything in a class. I guess you can even do this with simple powershell hashtables rather than using classes.

Comment: @iRon in a sense I think that is what I am doing. I "need" the circular reference to validate that the data in my XML is correct for the different products, but during regular execution I won't actually DO anything with that data till it's actually needed. But the data is loaded into the class, and the class injected into the workflow, so whenever there is a token in a customer provided string, I can replace the token with the correct data, like the correct registry path. Then and only then do I actually query the registry for the data the workflow is really after.